# Can we modify block gas limit in Kaleido?

Tags: kaleido

I am trying to deploy a smart contract on Kaleido Ethereum consortium, however, I am getting an error:

> Failed to deploy the smart contract. Error: Error: Returned error: exceeds block gas limit

Comment: Welcome to SE!, please have a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site.

Answer (score 1):

Kaleido does not yet provide the ability to customise the block gas limit. The `--targetgaslimit` on the nodes is unset, and you will see the default of 4712388.

Have you estimated the gas needed to successfully install your contract?
The 'exceeds block gas limit' error will be returned if you *request* more than 4712388 when submitting your transaction, regardless of whether the installation would have taken less than that value.
So it's worth checking it does fail when requesting exactly 4712388.

Comment: Update - we've just pushed a change to Kaleido so newly created, or upgraded, environments will have `--targetgaslimit 804247552` (which previously was the gas limit on the genesis block, but would decay down block by block to 4712388).